# Связь мужду адаптерами RecyclerView | Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Как связать два адаптера RV вместе?

Для чего мне это:
я пытаюсь создать подобие слайдера на веб-сайте(сверху только иконки, по нажатию на которые снизу перемещается на нужный слайд).

У меня это реализовано так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"

        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"

        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|left"
        android:text="@string/browse_potential_starlet"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/p_s_s"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView2" />

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/p_s_s_e"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/p_s_s">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

У вас есть адаптер с иконками. Вешаете на него клик листенер. Когда кликаете на один из элементов то вызываете на адаптере со списком

```
recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

До нужной вам позиции.

Обратная штука делается почти так же, только вы добавляете вот такую штуку в нижнему RecyclerView

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        if (dy > 0) {
            // Scrolling up
        } else {
            // Scrolling down
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    }
});
```

И когда доскроливаете до определенной позиции - переключаете элемент на верхнем списке.

```
layoutManager.findViewByPosition(position);
layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
```

вот эти 2 метода вам помогут проверить видимый элемент, чтоб понять когда надо переключать верхний список